# Magento 2: User and admin sign up without password validation

Tags: admin, login, magento-2.1.7, user, admin-login

Magento 2.1.7

User sign in with whatever password, also same admin logged in whatever password.

user and admin sign in without password validation

We are using godaddy dedicated server.

Two Case here

1. Customer user sign in at store. ex. customer user: abc@gmail.com and customer password is clear@2015. when customer enter password Focus!2018@ with abc@gmail.com user. then sign in with that password Focus!2018@ instead of that password clear@2015.
2. same scenario/situation with admin user

Comment: Welcome to MageSE, Your question is not clear, Please add more description to it. Like: what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far. It will be helpful to you to get more useful answers.

Comment: Are you asking for signup or signin ?

Comment: I have update more description

Comment: Whats the use case here? If the store isn't accessible online but only locally would it be okay for such, if it's accessible via the internet you're asking for all kinds of security issues with this approach.

Comment: my store is live but on demo server